# Measurement of billable social mentions consumed in salesforce radian6 (social studio)

Tags: marketing-cloud, radian6, social-studio

Salesforce social studio (part of salesforce marketing cloud) charges based on count of mentions tracked. As I've limited amount of credits available in my account to track mentions. Though I haven't found any window where I can track how manny mentions has been consumed or remaining.

Please suggest where can I find the above information in salesforce marketing cloud - social studio or radian6 panel.